# WPF Encapsulate rectangle with StaticResource as fill to a CustomControl in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, mahapps.metro

I am using ModernUIIcons that come with MahApps.Metro in a Xaml file as StaticResources. To put one in my UI is very easy, like this:

```
<Rectangle  Width="19" 
            Height="19">
   <Rectangle.Fill>
      <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource appbar_database}" />
   </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

I want to encapsulate all the logic of the rectangle in a CustomControl so I can do something like the following:

```
<cc:MenuItemIcon Source="{StaticResource appbar_page}"/>
```

**This is what I got so far:**

In one project as library, Themes/Generic.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AMIGEDM.CustomControls.Menu">

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MenuItemIcon}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MenuItemIcon}">
                <Rectangle  Width="19" 
                            Height="19">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <VisualBrush Visual="{TemplateBinding Source}" />
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And in the CS file

```
namespace AMIGEDM.CustomControls.Menu
{
   public class MenuItemIcon : Control
{
   static MenuItemIcon()
   {
      DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MenuItemIcon), new  FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MenuItemIcon)));
   }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("Source", typeof(Visual), typeof(MenuItemIcon));

   public Visual Source
   {
      get { return (Visual)GetValue(SourceProperty); }
      set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
   }
  }
}
```

Everything compiles silky smooth, so I go to my TestDummy Project

```
<Window x:Class="AMIGEDM.TestDummy.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:AMIGEDM.CustomControls.Menu;assembly=AMIGEDM.CustomControls">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/AMIGEDM.TestDummy;component/Resources/Icons.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/AMIGEDM.CustomControls;component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Menu IsMainMenu="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <MenuItem Header="_Open">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <cc:MenuItemIcon Source="{StaticResource appbar_page}"/>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Rectangle  Width="19" 
                            Height="19">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource appbar_database}" />
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

**The Library puts the Icon using the Rectangle, Rectangle Fill and VisualBrush, but when I try to use the CustomControl it shows nothing**

[image: As you see, the icon appears using the complete rectangle but not with my custom control]

Comment: I don't have a VS here to check it, but try this:
<MenuItem Header="_File" Icon="{StaticResource appbar_page}"/>

Comment: @Eyjafjallajokull thanks but I need to resize the icons, that's why I don't use them directly like that

Comment: Source="{StaticResource appbar_page} is a rectangle and Visual="{StaticResource appbar_database}" is a icon, if I understand right from your XAML. I mean give the key to a rectangle and set it as an Icon of the menu item instead of using custom control - as you do in a second menuitem that displayed right way but using resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the code looks normal, except for the style of `MenuItemIcon`. Quote about `TemplateBinding` from Adam Nathan book:

> TemplateBinding doesn’t work outside a template or outside its VisualTree property, so you can’t even use TemplateBinding inside a template’s trigger. Furthermore, 
>   TemplateBinding doesn’t work when applied to a Freezable (for mostly artificial reasons).

And quote from [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush.aspx) about `VisualBrush`:

> Freezable Features: Because it inherits from the Freezable class, the VisualBrush class provides several special features: VisualBrush objects can be declared as resources and shared among multiple objects.

Therefore instead of:

```
<VisualBrush Visual="{TemplateBinding Source}" />
```

Use the construction `{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}` and a `Path` equal to the dependency property whose value you want to retrieve:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MenuItemIcon}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MenuItemIcon}">
                <Rectangle Width="22" Height="22">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Source}" />                                
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```